# Is the word trackable used correctly here?

Tags: meaning, sentence

I want to phrase a sentence to say that:

> one could find easily the initial source location of an object.

Could we say that that object is easily *trackable*, in the sense of its original location?

Comment: Perhaps traceable is better than trackable. Trackable implies an ability to find in the present, and doesn't necessarily imply knowledge of past locations (although in context it might). So  I could track a car by finding it and following it, without knowing where it started its journey from.

Comment: How about adding the word source to trackable to get source trackable for the issue you mention

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest using "traceable". "trackable" usually implies you're finding something where it is now. If you're finding where it's been, you're "tracing back the path" as it were, which is why "traceable" sounds better.

Comment: ok then i will use that